# table stacked below sidebar when window size is reduced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Creating a website using bootstrap which consists of two columns. The first column is the side bar and the second consists of a table.

The page looks fine when the screen is not reduced in size.

But the table gets stacked below the sidebar when window is reduced in size.

I would like to table to remain next to the side bar.

http://www.bootply.com/128015

The code is as follows.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h1>&nbsp;LDSLDSLDLSDL</h1></a>

        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="" height="75px" width="337.5px"></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class=" bs-docs-sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav ">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Book an appointment </a></li><hr>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Search</a></li><hr>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Visits</a></li><hr>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Share Info</a></li><hr>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Association</a></li><hr>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Upload Document</a></li><hr>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody><tr class="success">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>TB - Monthly</td>
                    <td>01/04/2012</td>
                    <td>Approved</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On smaller resolutions, these elements don't have their styles anymore (because of some bootstrap media-query conditions), so you can add them back:

```
.col-md-2 { 
  width: 16.67%;
}
.col-md-10 { 
  width: 83.33%;
}
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 { 
  float: left;
}
```

If you add them on your own styles and make them more particular (by adding ".container-fluid" before each col-class) they will be overwritten and the table won't be stacked under anymore.

```
.container-fluid .col-md-2 { 
  width: 16.67%;
}
.container-fluid .col-md-10 { 
  width: 83.33%;
}
.container-fluid .col-md-1, .container-fluid .col-md-2, .container-fluid .col-md-3, .container-fluid .col-md-4, .container-fluid .col-md-5, .container-fluid .col-md-6, .container-fluid .col-md-7, .container-fluid .col-md-8, .container-fluid .col-md-9, .container-fluid .col-md-10, .container-fluid .col-md-11, .container-fluid .col-md-12 { 
  float: left;
}
```

Or just add "!important" after each style property.

```
 .col-md-2 { 
      width: 16.67% !important;
   }
    .col-md-10 { 
      width: 83.33% !important;
    }
    .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 { 
      float: left !important;
    }
```